# Axe culling blades instant kill Damage?

Tags: dota-2, dota

I Read somewhere that axe does 100000000 physical damage (killing blow). So if someone uses blademail during the killing blow, Will it kill axe??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. If the target is below the HP threshold, all buffs are dispelled and then they take killing damage. In Dota1 it was a ton of physical, but in Dota2 I think it's just a kill.

Comment: So it can kill a hero in bkb or repel?

Comment: @PremAnand Yes, it will go through magic immunity.

Comment: I wonder if it works against Dazzle's Shallow Grave because it dispell the effect, or because it counts as a kill :)

Comment: It goes through Shallow Grave, making Axe an extremely effective counter to Dazzle.

Comment: @jzacharia Yes, that's because all buffs are dispelled, even the ones that can't normally be dispelled like Shallow Grave.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Dota 2 Wiki](http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Axe) it still does 100,000,000 damage. Prior to dealing the damage all buffs are removed from the unit including blade mail.

Answer (score 2):

I can't post comments but it will go through Dazzle's Shallow Grave.

The only thing that stops Culling Blade from killing is having enough HP to start with.